# How to pull submodules from a subtree repo?

Tags: git

I want to add an external lib as a subtree. But this lib contains a submodule and I can't figure out how to get it.

I usually add a subtree manually, by adding a remote and use:

`git read-tree --prefix=remote -u remote/master`

Has anyone ever dealt with submodules in subtrees ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome @Jil. I haven't dealt with it at all, but have you simply tried `git submodule update --init --recursive` at the root repo? or at the subtree? (test in a disposable local copy just in case)

Comment: @A.M. Thanks, yes I tried, I have this weird error 'No url found for submodule in .gitmodule', while there is an url and its path in the .gitmodule file of the lib

Comment: Did you `cd` into your subtree repo before running `git submodule update --init --recursive`?

Comment: @Cubimon yes, I tried in the subtree and at the root of my project. Thx anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand the library has file `.gitmodules` at the top of the **library** tree. When the lib is included as a subtree in a superproject the file `.gitmodules` is in the subtree while `git` expects it at the top of the repository.

I can think of a few ways to work around the problem (symlink, copy) but my recommendation for this situation is to avoid subtree at all. You have to work with submodules anyway as the lib contains a submodule so why not make the very lib a submodule instead of a subtree?

Comment: Yes I think this is the issue. Indeed it might work with a symlink (and maybe change the path) of the .gitmodules but it is not ideal. I guess a subtree is not recommended when it uses submodules. Thank you!