# Importing as sub-tree a public repo containing sub-modules

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

For customizing a firmware (FW) from a github repository (which uses git-submodules), I was planning to 'import' this public repository as a git-subtree in my own repository.

In theory, I will never have to modify the original FW code but just make additions to an external folder that will be used during compilation.

I am fairly new to git but git-subtree seems convenient for grouping the original FW with the new content in a single repository, while 'freezing' the FW to a version (commit) compatible with the added scripts/configs.

Interestingly, the original FW repository contains mostly git-submodules and I don't know if I will be able to manage this nested situation (git-submodules inside a git-subtree).

If I do:

```
git subtree add --prefix officialFW https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/plutosdr-fw.git master --squash
```

I believe that the submodules content is not retrieved as when I make a `git clone --recurse-submodules`.
Should I `git pull` them manually afterwards ?

Any help on how to get that done is appreciated.

I would also appreciate comments on the sub-tree strategy for my use-case, or remarks about using them in this specific context (with nested submodules, should we avoid mixing them ?).

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57201596/7976758

Comment: Thank you for the comment, and sorry for the duplicate question. Your link basically suggests that git-subtree and git-submodule don't mix well together...
I think I'll go for git-submodule then but that's a pity as I felt  git-subtree would have been more adapted to my use-case (easier to pull changes from remote repositories, no need to push back local commits there).